# How to Remove a Sound Output Device Created by an Application

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, audio, catalina, midi

On my mid 2012 MBP running macOS 10.15.1 (Catalina) I had an application create a sound output device. I deleted the application in finder by moving it to the trash. I know this method doesn't uninstall any dependencies or extra things the application might have installed which is why I'm having this issue. I went into the Audio MIDI Setup, but the (-) symbol is greyed out for the output, which is named AudioJingle. How would I go about uninstalling this output device?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Posting here for  reference if you still have the problem and for other searching the answer was found at the [Apple Community Site](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250403945)

Remove the following files:

1. `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Audiojingle.driver`
2. `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.audiojinglex.soundtree.agent.plist`
3. `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.audiojinglex.soundtree.agent.plist`

Then restart coreaudiod using terminal `sudo /bin/launchctl kill SIGTERM system/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod || /usr/bin/killall coreaudiod`

or use the following script it does the same thing (I personally did it manually)

```
#!/bin/bash

# remove driver
DRIVER_NAME="Audiojingle.driver"
DRIVER_INSTALL_PATH="/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/${DRIVER_NAME}"
if [  -d "${DRIVER_INSTALL_PATH}" ]; then
    /bin/rm -rf "${DRIVER_INSTALL_PATH}" || exit 1
fi

# remove helper plist

LAUNCHD_PLIST_INSTALL_PATH="/Library/LaunchDaemons"
LAUNCHD_PLIST_INSTALL_PATH_BACKUP="/Library/LaunchAgents"
LAUNCHD_PLIST_FILENAME="com.audiojinglex.soundtree.agent.plist"
LAUNCHD_PLIST="${LAUNCHD_PLIST_INSTALL_PATH}/${LAUNCHD_PLIST_FILENAME}"
LAUNCHD_PLIST_BACKUP="${LAUNCHD_PLIST_INSTALL_PATH_BACKUP}/${LAUNCHD_PLIST_FILENAME}"

# romove the plist.
if [ -e "${LAUNCHD_PLIST}" ]; then
    /bin/rm -f "${LAUNCHD_PLIST}"
fi

if [ -e "${LAUNCHD_PLIST_BACKUP}" ]; then
    /bin/rm -f "${LAUNCHD_PLIST_BACKUP}"
fi

#/usr/bin/killall -u "_coreaudiod" "coreaudiod"
/bin/launchctl kill SIGTERM system/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod || /usr/bin/killall coreaudiod

echo "restart coreaudio"

sleep 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple approach, but it's amazing just how often the simple approach does the trick.

In *both* `~/Library` & `/Library` enter the name of the thing you want rid of in the Finder window search box, & select "Name Matches" when it appears.

[image: Name Matches]

The user Library, `~/Library`, is hidden in recent versions of mac OS, so use Command-Shift-g (or using menus, Go > Go to Folder...) to get there. I added it to the Favourites sextion of my Finder sidebar so I don't have to continue doing this.

[image: Finder sidebar]

While you're in those Library folders, a scan of the folder names within might reveal likely locations for what you're looking for. In my `~/Library` there's a folder `/Audio` for example.

Also look in `/Application Support` & `/Preferences` within both Library folders, & looking by reverse domain sytle identifiers as well as direct names, for anything left behind by your deeted app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this and deleted all the instances of AudioJingle and the software it came from but the problem is still persisting.